# What happen in JSminify process taken by in between two JS independently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

I wrote two JS's. one(one.js) has a function definition another one(two.js) has a function call.

for example my code like this

```
// one.js
function log(){
   console.log("logged successfully...");
}
//two .js 
log();
```

In my case, I have a doubt first I run the minifying process individually. After I getting the minified js(one.min.js), Then I include one.min.js and two.js in HTML page.

1) Is it possible to call available log function from two.js?

Please answer my question.

Comment: No, because it'd be highly likely that the `log` function would be renamed to something else

Comment: You probably can't. The minified `log()` will be transformed into something like `t()`. In two.js, it doesn't know `log()` has become `t()`, so it keeps calling `log()` which will throw error `Function log() is not defined.`.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I further question is here, I wrote a piece a module split from my project code base. minify this module first, and include to my project. Is there a way to work for it?. the whole project at a time change as module based code. It is not possible.